# Suppose k be a positive integer such that k divides p-1, where p is a prime. Prove that $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$ has an element of order k.

Tags: group-theory

Suppose k be a positive integer such that k divides p-1, where p is a prime. Prove that $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$ has an element of order k.

I think this is suppose to be the converse of Lagrange.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $k$ divides $p-1$ then we must have an element $m$ such that $km=p-1$. Now take an element in your group, say $a$. Then, $(a^m)^k=a^{(p-1)}=1$, by [Fermat's Little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Comment: This shows that $a^m$ has order **at most** $k$, maybe not actually $k$.

Comment: @David: That's why this is a hint. It's easy to get over this difficulty. It's not right to give the full solution for a HW problem.

Comment: @David: In fact, unfortunately your and mine solution can be combined to give a full solution for this HW problem :(

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  Suppose that $p-1=km$ where $m$ is a positive integer.  Let $g$ be a primitive root (or *primitive element*, or *generator*) modulo $p$.  Then see what you can say about
$$g^m\,,\ g^{2m}\,,\ \ldots\,,\ g^{(k-1)m}$$
and
$$g^{km}\ .$$

Comment: Does there always exist a primitive root?

Comment: @sarah Yes! See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n